# Trying to access psql after dropping a user but still got asked for entering password for the dropped user

Tags: postgresql, psql

initially I have

```
Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 hezhenghao | Create DB                                                  | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

and I typed

```
postgres=# REASSIGN OWNED BY hezhenghao to postgres
postgres-# ;
REASSIGN OWNED
postgres=# REASSIGN OWNED BY hezhenghao to postgres;                                                                                                 REASSIGN OWNED
postgres=# DROP OWNED BY hezhenghao;
DROP OWNED
postgres=# DROP USER hezhenghao;
DROP ROLE
```

Now there is only one user

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

However when I type `psql` in terminal, I still got asked to `Password for user hezhenghao:`
and then I would end up with `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "hezhenghao"`

I am new to `postgres` so I don't really understand what's going on here. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a user with -U then psql will default to the username of the user currently logged in.  In this case, it sounds like that user is hezhenghao.  Use -U postgres to log in as the postgres user.

Comment: thanks. it works! A quick question, if I use the CLI utility `createdb` without going to `psql`, then the database I created belongs to which user? How does Postgres determine this?

Comment: Same as in the answer.